# Change div color by finding input background-color

Tags: javascript, html, forms

How do I change the JavaScript code to find the `input` `label`'s HTML `background-color` instead of having to manually insert the color into the JavaScript like in this snippet?

```js
function ChangeColor(color) {
  var clrDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("colorDiv")[0];
  clrDiv.style.backgroundColor = color;
}

document.getElementById("select1").onclick = function() {
  ChangeColor("red");
}
document.getElementById("select2").onclick = function() {
  ChangeColor("green");
}
document.getElementById("select3").onclick = function() {
  ChangeColor("blue");
}
```

```css
.colorDiv {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <input id="select1" name="test" type="radio" />
  <label style="background-color:red;" for="select1">Red</label>
  <input id="select2" name="test" type="radio" />
  <label style="background-color:green;" for="select2">Green</label>
  <input id="select3" name="test" type="radio" />
  <label style="background-color:blue;" for="select3">Blue</label>
</section>
<footer>
  <div class="colorDiv"></div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are looking for? Instead of a color, I pass the id of the select, find the label for the input, and then use that label's background color to set the div background color.

If you are alright using jquery this could be greatly simplified.

```js
function findLableForControl(el) {
   var idVal = el.id;
   labels = document.getElementsByTagName('label');
   for( var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++ ) {
      if (labels[i].htmlFor == idVal)
           return labels[i];
   }
}

function ChangeColor(color) {
    var clrDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("colorDiv")[0];
    clrDiv.style.backgroundColor = findLableForControl(document.getElementById(color)).style.backgroundColor;;
}

document.getElementById("select1").onclick = function() { ChangeColor("select1"); }
document.getElementById("select2").onclick = function() { ChangeColor("select2"); }
document.getElementById("select3").onclick = function() { ChangeColor("select3"); }
```

```css
.colorDiv{
 width:50px;
 height:50px;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <input id="select1" name="test" type="radio" />
        <label style="background-color:red;" for="select1">Red</label>
    <input id="select2" name="test" type="radio" />
        <label style="background-color:green;" for="select2">Green</label>
    <input id="select3" name="test" type="radio" />
        <label style="background-color:blue;" for="select3">Blue</label>
</section>
<footer>
    <div class="colorDiv"></div>
</footer>
```

Comment: *If you are alright using jQuery this could be greatly simplified*. Hmmm, It can be *greatly simplified* without jQuery. You don't need the anonymous functions, the color parameter, the `document.getElementById(color)`, the `idVal` variable, and the loop. Now your JavaScript function will only be 2 lines like in my answer (you can even merge them into 1 line). jQuery will only save you a few more characters ;).

Comment: Is there an alternative for handling dynamic data? i.e not having to identify each ID in the JS?

Answer (score 0):

You can make your code much simpler by following a few easy steps:

- Assign the `ChangeColor` function directly to the `onclick`, no need for an intermediary anonymous function and no need to pass anything.
- In the `ChangeColor` function, use `this` to access the element that raised the event (i.e. the `input` that you clicked on).
- Use the `querySelector` function to select the associated label by its `for` attribute.

```js
function ChangeColor() {
  var clrDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("colorDiv")[0];
  clrDiv.style.backgroundColor = document.querySelector("label[for=" + this.id + "]").style.backgroundColor;
}

document.getElementById("select1").onclick = ChangeColor;
document.getElementById("select2").onclick = ChangeColor;
document.getElementById("select3").onclick = ChangeColor;
```

```css
.colorDiv {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <input id="select1" name="test" type="radio" />
  <label style="background-color:red;" for="select1">Red</label>
  <input id="select2" name="test" type="radio" />
  <label style="background-color:green;" for="select2">Green</label>
  <input id="select3" name="test" type="radio" />
  <label style="background-color:blue;" for="select3">Blue</label>
</section>
<footer>
  <div class="colorDiv"></div>
</footer>
```